# How Update data if already exists else insert using typeORM and Nestjs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm, nest, upsert

I have table which contains the id, user_id, skill(will be unique for user), category (can be duplicated)etc.
I want to store data like if skill already added by user, the skill should be overriden or remained as it is if already Exists otherwise simply insert in db.

In short skill should be unique for each user

I am using postgresql for db and typeORM with nestjs.

Comment: See [Insert ... On Colflict ...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-insert.html). You will have to translate into your obscurification manager (typeORM).